# Ionic error: Unfortunately AppName has stopped

Tags: android, ionic-framework

Here is lot of question with this subject regarding Android, but not Ionic. I got same problem - application build successfully but this error then. How can I fix this?
P.S. I did tried remove and add again android platform as well as increase and decrese size of RAM in emulator.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, the solution was simple - just create new virtual device.

Answer (score 0):

***Try this :***

**1-** delete com.ionic.keyboard from the plugins folder

**2-** re-install com.ionic.keyboard in same folder

**3-** delete any ios or android.json files in this folder

**4-** rebuild

**5-** ionic run android

Comment: There is only ionic-plugin-keyboard present, but no plugin with te name you mention.

Comment: generally the problem is with keyboard.

Comment: This did not helped as well as there is no json files in  plugin folder.